# How to bind Array of JSON in Angular Dual-Listbox

Tags: angular5

i am using "[Angular Dual-Listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-dual-listbox#angular-dual-listbox)", 
i created demo it worked fine , but when i am adding json array as a source it will not showing anything on ui.

**comp.html**

```
     <dual-list [source]="source" [(destination)]="confirmed"></dual-list>
```

**comp.ts**

```
  export class UploadQuestionSetComponent implements OnInit {
     source: any;
     confirmed = [];
     target = [];
      constructor(private uploadQuestionSetService : uploadQuestionSetService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        //following array works fine
        //this.source = ["bhagvat","kailash","rakesh"];

       //but i need to bind json array 
        this.source = [
         { "id": "1", "name": "bhagvat"},
         {"id": "2","name": "kailas"},
         {"id": "3","name": "rakesh"}]

      }
    }
```

as per the documentation they provided :

- key - The unique identifier field of each object in the source and
  destination arrays, default is _id. (Note: with a source of an array
  of strings, each string is its own id.)
- display - The field of each
  object for displaying the object each the lists, default is _name.
  Or, a function that returns a string that can be used for displaying
  an object. (Note: with a source of an array of strings, each string
  is its own display.)

i tested this but it wont showing anything , can you please see here , thanks

Answer (score 3):

after spending 3-4 hrs finally i am here with solution to my question :)

```
 <dual-list [source]="source"  key="id" display="name"  [(destination)]="confirmed"></dual-list>
```

- you need to add key="id"  is a unique id for each object.
- display="name" is a name filed which is to be displayed.